# How to move one table data to another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

There is one table say department in which data is present.

```
create table department(deptno number, deptname varchar2(50), deptloc varchar2(50));

insert into department values(1,'A','X');
insert into department values(2,'B','Y');
insert into department values(3,'C','Z');

select * from department;
```

I want to move this data to another table say Department_SP using stored procedure. Basically, I wanted to know how we will move the data from one table to another using certain conditions or filters that will be performed using the stored procedure. Just I want an idea of how this will be done. I would appreciate it if you guys have any examples like this then please share your views on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```
... all your code...
-- create table department_cp with same structure as department but empty.
CREATE TABLE department_cp AS SELECT * FROM department WHERE 1 = 2;

SELECT * FROM department_cp;

-- nothing

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure copy_data
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO department_cp SELECT * FROM department;
END;
/

exec copy_data;

SELECT * FROM department_cp;

-- same as department.
```

So what is your actual question ?

Comment: Thanks. Can you share some complex examples if you have wherein we are applying some logic or filters then inserting them into another table? Your example gives a clear picture of what I was expecting but please share with me some complex examples as mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Define “complex”. Your requirement is very vague.

Comment: Just add a where clause after ```FROM department``` You can make it as complex as you wish. I suggest you play with it.

Comment: @KoenLostrie - Actually you don't really need a stored procedure - unless there are other unstated requirements.  The actual solution is, as shown, just a simple SQL statement.  Of course, if this is a repeated process, run on some sort of schedule, then a SP might be warranted.  But then, on the other hand,  why do you want to copy data from one table to another.  Without further info, this smacks of being an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @EdStevens thanks Ed, I realise that but the OP specifically asked for it.

Comment: This functionality is called [materialized view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B), which has, well, a much better manageability, it is completely clear and understandable by everyone and provide fast refresh out of the box and doesn't require additional boilerplate PL/SQL. Compared to such homegrown solution.

Comment: @astentx only if you don't want to modify the copied data is an MV an option. OP did not indicate this was the case.

Comment: @KoenLostrie Most of the modifications may be done via SQL. When data modification requires PL/SQL it should be something very complex. Developers that really need this do not ask such questions (how to `insert ... select ...`)

Comment: @KoenLostrie I've just added a where clause that you asked for in my answer.

Comment: _" I realise that but the OP specifically asked for it"_    And if they specifically asked for instructions on shooting themselves in the foot?

Answer (score 1):

Create customers table

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(customer_id number(10) NOT NULL, customer_name varchar2(50),city varchar2(50));
```

Insert data to customers the table

```
insert into customers (customer_id, customer_name, city) values (1,'Adam','Washington');
insert into customers (customer_id, customer_name, city) values (2,'Ben','NY');
insert into customers (customer_id, customer_name, city) values (3,'Carl','Baltimore');
```

Create table for cities

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(city_id number(10) NOT NULL, city_name varchar2(50));
```

Insert data to cities table

```
insert into cities (city_id, city_name) values (1, 'Washington');
insert into cities (city_id, city_name) values (2, 'Los Angeles');
insert into cities (city_id, city_name) values (3, 'Chicago');
```

Create customers copy table (empty)

```
CREATE TABLE customers_cp AS SELECT * FROM customers where 1=0;
```

Insert data to customers copy if the person's city is in the cities table list

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_CP SELECT * FROM customers where city in (select city_name from cities);
```

Now the CUSTOMERS_CP table only contains 1 row which is Adam, Washington.